# Java -vending machine that can't accept pennies

Tags: java

So I'm working on a java project that involves creating a soda machine that adjusts price based on temperature. I can't seem to figure out how to make sure the machine does NOT accept pennies when accepting payment from the user.

I feel like I'm overcoding but I'm at my wit's end because I don't have any clue how to not accept pennies.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class SodaMachine extends SodaTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double temp;
        double money;
        double change;
        double price1 = .50;
        double price2 = .55;
        double price3 = .60;
        double price4 = .65;
        double price5 = .75;
        double price6 = .80;
        double price7 = .85;
        double price8 = .90;
        double price9 = 1.00;

        System.out.println("Hi there! Please enter the temperature in Farenheit:");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        temp = scan.nextDouble();
        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.#");

        NumberFormat fmt2 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        if (temp < 40 || temp > 120)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Temperature should be between 40 and 120 degrees Farenheit.");
            while (temp < 40 || temp > 120)
            {
                temp = scan.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("The rounded temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " + fmt.format(temp));
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Temperature should be between 40 and 120 degrees Farenheit.");
            }
        }

        if(temp < 50 && temp >= 40)
        {
            System.out.println("The rounded temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " + fmt.format(temp));
            System.out.println("The price is: " + fmt2.format(price1));

            System.out.println("Please insert amount of payment: ");
            money = scan.nextDouble();
            while (money < price1)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input please try again. Your total is: " + fmt2.format(price1));
                money = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            change = money - price1;
            System.out.println("Your Change is: " + fmt2.format(change));
        }else if (temp >= 50 && temp <= 60) {
            System.out.println("The rounded temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " + fmt.format(temp));
            System.out.println("The price is: " + fmt2.format(price2));

            System.out.println("Please insert amount of payment: ");
            money = scan.nextDouble();
            while (money < price2)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input please try again. Your total is: " + fmt2.format(price2));
                money = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            change = money - price2;
            System.out.println("Your Change is: " + fmt2.format(change));
        }else if (temp > 60 && temp <= 65) { 
            System.out.println("The rounded temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " + fmt.format(temp));
            System.out.println("The price is: " + fmt2.format(price3));

            System.out.println("Please insert amount of payment: ");
            money = scan.nextDouble();
            while (money < price3)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input please try again. Your total is: " + fmt2.format(price3));
                money = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            change = money - price3;
            System.out.println("Your Change is: " + fmt2.format(change));
        }else if (temp > 65 && temp <= 70) {
            System.out.println("The rounded temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " + fmt.format(temp));
            System.out.println("The price is: " + fmt2.format(price4));

            System.out.println("Please insert amount of payment: ");
            money = scan.nextDouble();
            while (money < price4)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input please try again. Your total is: " + fmt2.format(price4));
                money = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            change = money - price4;
            System.out.println("Your Change is: " + fmt2.format(change));
        }else if (temp > 70 && temp <= 75) {
            System.out.println("The rounded temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " + fmt.format(temp));
            System.out.println("The price is: " + fmt2.format(price5));

            System.out.println("Please insert amount of payment: ");
            money = scan.nextDouble();
            while (money < price5)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input please try again. Your total is: " + fmt2.format(price5));
                money = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            change = money - price5;
            System.out.println("Your Change is: " + fmt2.format(change));
        }else if (temp > 75 && temp <= 80) {
            System.out.println("The rounded temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " + fmt.format(temp));
            System.out.println("The price is: " + fmt2.format(price6));

            System.out.println("Please insert amount of payment: ");
            money = scan.nextDouble();
            while (money < price6)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input please try again. Your total is: " + fmt2.format(price6));
                money = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            change = money - price6;
            System.out.println("Your Change is: " + fmt2.format(change));
        }else if (temp > 80 && temp <= 85) {
            System.out.println("The rounded temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " + fmt.format(temp));
            System.out.println("The price is: " + fmt2.format(price7));

            System.out.println("Please insert amount of payment: ");
            money = scan.nextDouble();
            while (money < price7)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input please try again. Your total is: " + fmt2.format(price7));
                money = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            change = money - price7;
            System.out.println("Your Change is: " + fmt2.format(change));
        }else if (temp > 85 && temp <= 90) {
            System.out.println("The rounded temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " + fmt.format(temp));
            System.out.println("The price is: " + fmt2.format(price8));

             System.out.println("Please insert amount of payment: ");
            money = scan.nextDouble();
            while (money < price8)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input please try again. Your total is: " + fmt2.format(price8));
                money = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            change = money - price8;
            System.out.println("Your Change is: " + fmt2.format(change));
        }else if (temp > 90 && temp <= 120) {
            System.out.println("The rounded temperature in degrees Farenheit is: " + fmt.format(temp));
            System.out.println("The price is: " + fmt2.format(price9));

            System.out.println("Please insert amount of payment: ");
            money = scan.nextDouble();
            while (money < price9)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input please try again. Your total is: " + fmt2.format(price9));
                money = scan.nextDouble();
            }
            change = money - price9;
            System.out.println("Your Change is: " + fmt2.format(change));
        }
    }






















}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We can't answer without seeing the code you have. Please update your question ([edit] and past the code as text). We don't need all the code. Probably just the part where you input the money. Visit the [help] and read about creating a [mcve].

Comment: Do you mean to only allow the use to enter values that end in "0" or "5". So, "1.23" is invalid but "1.20" is ok?

Comment: Well, the requirements basically says "NO PENNIES" can be accept from user input, and the max price is $1.00 so if user can't input $1.01 but they can input $1.05

Comment: I just don't know how to put that in the code

Comment: I can give change in pennies though.

Comment: @Devil'sBride So you want to check if the input by the user is rounded to 5 cents? So `1.00`, `2.05`, `4.35` are all acceptable, but `1.01`, `3.21`, `4.68` are not?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yeah. Basically, I'm quite bad with this stuff but as long as they input an amount of money that doesn't comprise of pennies ($1.01, $1.09, $4.11), I will be able to give them change.

Answer (score 2):

I won't go into detail about your current code, but you basically want to check if the decimal value you've read from the user modulo-`0.05` equals `0` (so it has no remainder). One issue in this is that floating point precision can interfere with the checks when you use `double`, which is why you'd always want to use `java.math.BigDecimal` for currency calculations.

Here an example:

```
BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal(scanner.next());
if(input.remainder(new BigDecimal("0.05")).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0){
  System.out.println("Input "+input+" is valid!");
} else{
  System.out.println("Input "+input+" is not valid!");
}
```

For the inputs `"1"`, `"1.00"`, `"1.05"`, `"4.35"`, `"1.01"`, `"3.21"`, `"4.68"` it will output the following:

```
Input 1 is valid!
Input 1.00 is valid!
Input 1.05 is valid!
Input 4.35 is valid!
Input 1.01 is not valid!
Input 3.21 is not valid!
Input 4.68 is not valid!
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##lU/BToQwEL33K0ZOJRsbcMWYEC5GDx7URDxp9lChwmAphBZWY/h2LCwLRk9eZtr35r15U/COnxbp@zBgWVeNgcICrDUoWZxwpUQTkp9MyU3OrjC7FgmWXIYkkVxruOOovghA3b5KTEAbbmzrKkyhtBSNTYMqe9kBbzLtjpMAsz/ouUegxP6I0vhTG1EyVG44Te9zlILOsyzn@l58GOrOXgBrJkBVt2a2W@FFqw7CcBbiG50ErBFj1NTu/iV0POYFjuuypCpr3oiniq4se755fHAhisBbstjbDukra1vby41U1LmdYjmbadvGAdTQcYnpibNk6UFILf5toyrz14oca0/6YfCJzzxvLAE5Z9tgfPlky858@724/AY)

---

Since `BigDecimal` can be quite confusing for new Java users, you could perhaps let the user input the amount in cents (so as integers), in which case it can be something like this instead:

```
int input = scanner.nextInt();
if(input % 5 == 0){
  System.out.println("Input "+input+" is valid!");
} else{
  System.out.println("Input "+input+" is not valid!");
}
```

For the input `"100"`, `"105"`, `"435"`, `"101"`, `"321"`, `"468"` it will output the following:

```
Input 100 is valid!
Input 105 is valid!
Input 435 is valid!
Input 101 is not valid!
Input 321 is not valid!
Input 468 is not valid!
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##lY7BaoQwEIbveYqpUIgsG7S7loJ4Kb3sob14LD2kmuq4MYoZ3Zbis9vU1aWwpx6SH2a@@WYqOchtlR@nCeu26QgqVxA9oRZpJo1RXcz@dmpJpXjE4kllWEsds0xLa@FZovlmAG3/rjEDS5JcDA3mULsWT6lDU7y@gewK6/@SAIsf7JIJGHVaqzz9sqRqgcaPZ/pUolZ8YUUp7Yv6JO4vLgA05F7bk/OslHHIwTgqXqEPfmZuIYIkgeAy7s45L2x6Eq07lrTh3mGGvc08tPEALQxSY37jXZQjKG3VvzWmoWsVW/@RjdMUBgELg4jtd5HLkO3uQra/f/gB)

---

EDIT: Since I had some time, I reworked your solution with re-usable methods.

Please have a good look what I did, and if you have any questions about specific parts let me know. It now uses recursive methods until the user enters a valid input. The `boolean showMessage` parameters in the methods are to show the `"Please enter X"` messages only once.

```
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;
import java.lang.NumberFormatException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SodaMachine{ 
  private static final String currencySymbol = "$";
  private static final BigDecimal roundOn = new BigDecimal("0.05");
  private Scanner scanner;
  private NumberFormat currencyFormat;

  public SodaMachine(){
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    SodaMachine sodaMachine = new SodaMachine();
    double farenheitInput = sodaMachine.enterFarenheit(true);
    System.out.println("The temperature in degrees Farenheit you've entered is: " + farenheitInput);

    BigDecimal price = sodaMachine.determinePrice(farenheitInput);
    System.out.println("The price is: " + sodaMachine.currencyFormat.format(price));

    BigDecimal payment = sodaMachine.enterPayment(price, true);

    BigDecimal change = payment.subtract(price);
    System.out.println("Your change is: " + sodaMachine.currencyFormat.format(change));
  }

  private double enterFarenheit(boolean showMessage){
    if(showMessage){
      System.out.println("Hi there! Please enter the temperature in Farenheit:");
    }

    double farenheitInput;
    try{
      farenheitInput = scanner.nextDouble();
    } catch(InputMismatchException ex){
      scanner.nextLine(); // Get rid of the invalid user-input
      System.out.println("The value you've entered is not a valid. The input should be a decimal input. Please try again.");
      return enterFarenheit(false);
    }

    if(farenheitInput < 40 | farenheitInput > 120){
      System.out.println("Invalid input. Temperature should be between 40 and 120 degrees Farenheit.");
      return enterFarenheit(false);
    }

    return farenheitInput;
  }

  private BigDecimal determinePrice(double farenheit){
    String strPrice;
    // Temperature is in the range [40, 50):
    if(farenheit >= 40 && farenheit < 50){
      strPrice = "0.50";
    }
    // Temperature is in the range [50, 60]:
    else if(farenheit >= 50 && farenheit <=60){
      strPrice = "0.55";
    }
    // Temperature is in the range (60, 65]:
    else if(farenheit > 60 && farenheit <= 65){
      strPrice = "0.60";
    }
    // Temperature is in the range (65, 70]:
    else if(farenheit > 65 && farenheit <= 70){
      strPrice = "0.65";
    }
    // Temperature is in the range (70, 75]:
    else if(farenheit > 70 && farenheit <= 75){
      strPrice = "0.75";
    }
    // Temperature is in the range (75, 80]:
    else if(farenheit > 75 && farenheit <= 80){
      strPrice = "0.80";
    }
    // Temperature is in the range (80, 85]:
    else if(farenheit > 80 && farenheit <= 85){
      strPrice = "0.85";
    }
    // Temperature is in the range (85, 90]:
    else if(farenheit > 85 && farenheit <= 90){
      strPrice = "0.90";
    }
    // Temperature is in the range (90, 120]:
    else if(farenheit > 90 && farenheit <= 120){
      strPrice = "1.00";
    }
    // Invalid temperature range:
    else{
      // Since we already validated the input-range, it should never go here,
      // but added it just in case.
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The temperature must be in the range [40, 120]!");
    }
    return new BigDecimal(strPrice);
  }

  private BigDecimal enterPayment(BigDecimal price, boolean showMessage){
    if(showMessage){
      System.out.println("Please enter amount of payment: ");
    }

    String userInput = scanner.next();
    // Remove the optional currency symbol from the user input
    userInput = userInput.replace(currencySymbol, "");

    BigDecimal paymentInput;
    try{
      paymentInput = new BigDecimal(userInput);
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
      scanner.nextLine(); // Get rid of the invalid user-input
      System.out.println("The value you've entered is not a valid. The input should be a price input. Please try again.");
      return enterPayment(price, false);
    }

    if(paymentInput.compareTo(price) < 0){
      System.out.println("Your payment of " + currencyFormat.format(paymentInput) + " is too low. Please try again. The total price is: " + currencyFormat.format(price));
      return enterPayment(price, false);
    }

    if(paymentInput.remainder(roundOn).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0){
      System.out.println("Your payment should be rounded to " + currencyFormat.format(roundOn) + ". Please try again.");
      return enterPayment(price, false);
    }

    return paymentInput;
  }
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##zVddb9s2FH33r7gxhs7GHFUd6q9mKbCt7RZgWYMmL1vRB1q6tplRpEFRdowuvz27pChbliytHvowoEgT8fIensPL@3HP1uz8Pv7r6YknK6UN3NOHQDC5CK6EwAUTP@pFlqA0bx8iXBmu5EWnZvp7lsxQv1M6YU12tLIMfuKLNxjxhInDRYMP5sDJ4XJmuAiu5Coz1zyl1WjZAOIMbyMmJeqLTiRYmsI14/IzPH8OV7BkawSjIGJCADduCeifWfIUlBRcIkQqWXGBegCzzICa04dMp5jbkGeYIWzpE9yqmF2zaGk3cZkaZHEHYKX5mhmE1DDDI5hzyQTcGs3lAqJMa5TR9nabzJSAS@h@071o2rOXCrTKZPxe0gaJm9JCrxsG4bDbL/vw5CEtRNgvlfXdnaWQ29plM0HwVpRe/zN9gMKLR/a@e7dbYpsEXDpkqPgi4zJSsEDzsze4IpmYjLDnNj6WQD31teIxJPYAuWQfPwHTi9Sfxl1XWpI9P1Z@4PwosSJ/CHNGeEvkxgUN2ZV2BRTLdLjComd0hn63J6YyE5Bo0gjZ694t6e4xWaFmJtP2qiHGhUZMYefDBsS3FFrOM8bA01fQhe8qx@g7laF8s4QSYeV4MZKThH67sYu9mo@2g@b@Cviy18M7Cubuv56z7x87GNvaN39MuZt8Kd87AC9f1UG0pLxgqXlPQZrNjGZRgdnM4w/7uPz2L2eSb@iXAstHvY@IyqXPlBJIjzldqs01pimjvXmQ8Xmv/vH4SX/llBXows/ghpylHsR@q0bMDvhV1zN/7DTHa25h9LYAr4dz/hIDSXnzjXNRPIBHylGUH3vHsyXgw45R2cdvJCx5sFnyFzSg6RVS5rNEuFwzQX9mKepzbp22CGJDkMwzrD8IkMoAA@csgDvn2XIhrTMR26TK6F3lseNWgkJU0gHYgt54UGgHoJGUldVLnTOR4qG@dJsV8X6AlyH8XZX0Nbz4Pmy97CsvhD/cXemC9xxmaDaI0kIwGVuf9WTxX2h4w3qYHIR66flVkkg1zDxTX5dSo51ZDkkxUCZHV@cqJIJ2T/Ljy3AAw7D/qqYvvL60xJ892@OQ2sO9rAWOrXxhMAy7BccvgR0S7Cj8lMMiKVTDHlaxL0eN2MNTsHsjiz1sxqaDVaHJvgF7FJ6GPRzAOGzDHtawx028R6fxHhPvcRvvcZ33uIn3@ERs4j1p4z2u85408Z6cpvmEeE/aeE/qvCdNvCen8Z4Q72kb70md97SJ9/Q03lPiTTmrBXxaJ15OnGX0F0FYQy@SaLk8Ouw9YuGKrG859YqwodIgNHXX27x6UKaLfWmiJHjutg9sN@/TsMQ1FeGFAluaB3tvtp1ncWyrEU0LWWos@YgqTOBtzFKrjesomyafejeYWD8zPJIirY5n@2pfyuKVJr7QrN@Wzw86r2oDSaPK12hnDpoYltDQ4eYf38BRI3ZYk3zxsI3BsbakaEhI@Q@YKDt4kUDK6Wj7Q9/FQZoPQ3OtEmdh/cG@0Si73/0eaFwJRnXtcKIaQLfb3Mseb63Ki/UBa4dY6a6Ozrv/7@bKjwYntVaVVv@wMbE/ixArqxjYCZoSxJ3yrT41Ae2tlev4i4mDpLEdf8O8UsLpk1XXkjdKgVCbI6ycFEaZ3aRVzBP/Mg2dqMRRFTTaOTamcdmP7/2SMPsQC/58@@F9H84uT9Fof6/Ot82HqoVXcQAr2Fe@e7@j@sQeO49PT3d0L5ES8VlnNOlcK4nbju286Md02rHV4R8)

Comment: When I tried using your suggested solutions, the program is even weirder. If I enter $.51 then it says no pennies to be accepted, which is fine but when I enter $1.00, it also said no pennies to be accepted.

Comment: I'm horrible at this to be honest haha

Comment: @Devil'sBride Hi there. I reworked your entire program and added it to the bottom of my answer. Please have a good look at everything I changed, and most importantly, make sure you understand everything I did. If you have any questions feel free to ask. :) PS: I've only briefly tested it, so I'm not sure it's 100% without errors.

Comment: @Devil'sBride I've tested it a bit, and fixed a few minor bugs. Because I have to add all input at once in TIO instead of one by one as in your actual program, I'm not entire sure if the `.next()` and `.nextLine()` are correct here. Everything else seems to work.

Comment: hey, thanks so much! I tested it with a few values (for the payment) I tried both $.57 AND $1.11 which were both accepted and change were given but this shouldn't be possible since the amount were comprised of pennies.

Comment: Is there anything I should try and input into the code to change this?

Comment: @Devil'sBride Ah oops.. I changed your complete program, but forgot to add the part about not accepting pennies.. >.> Woops.. My bad! I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: @Devil'sBride Now the rounding check is also added.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You spare so many bytes in codegolf that you have to unleash here? ;-)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Rofl. I'm a Java developer at work, so I already unleash there. I sometimes actually have to restrain myself from codegolfing our code when I'm refactoring. Especially when I use regexes that my junior colleague developers barely understand. xD

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Hi! I just saw the code you uploaded and it looks so much better than mine (seriously though.) Any tips on how I can get the same output but using 2 classes?

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified alot, but I will focus on the issue at hand.

I would create a function to get user input, ensuring it does not contain pennies:

```
double getMoney(String prompt, Scanner scan)
{
    double money = 0;
    while(true) {   // Loop until proper input
        System.out.println(prompt);
        money = scan.nextDouble();
        // There are a few ways to determine if it has pennies.
        // I will convert to int and check if it is divisible
        // by 10 or 5
        int i = (int)Math.round(money * 100);  // Convert to pennies
        if (0 == i % 5) {
            // It's ok, return
            return money;
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: using floating point for currency is bad practice. Floating point can introduce rounding errors. It's better to use integers and store the values using the lowest denomination. In this case pennies.

Comment: Oooh. I see. Also, on the simplification side, Can you give me an example as to where I could simplify the code? I tend to over code everything and it is really a bad habit.

Comment: Whenever you have code repeated like that, it's a sign you can simplify.

Comment: Since `10` is divisible by `5`, only `0 == i % 5` would already suffice, you don't need the `0 == i % 10` check. Also, floating point errors can occur here, even when you multiply by 100 and cast to int. [For example, `4.35` becomes `434` and therefore gives an incorrect result.](https://ideone.com/jfGVvf) EDIT: I now see your added side note. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I've update to use `Math.round` which seems to work better than the `int` cast.